# Why do my Next.js Commerce Store and Shopify checkout have different URLS

Tags: url, shopify, shopify-app

I created shopify storefront with Next.JS Commerce with my own domain ( mystoredomain.com ) when I proceed to checkout it directs me to my generic shopify store with a generic url ( blahblahwhatever.myshopify.com ) which is hidden since its not in use. I want the shopify checkout to keep using my storefront ( mystoredomain.com ) URL. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Tried to see if I could switch the domain on my shopify template domain to ( mystoredomain.com ) but then my next.js commerce app doesnt have the correct domain.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect a domain to your store:

```
https://admin.shopify.com/store/{STORE_NAME}/settings/domains/connect
```

(You will need to setup a DNS address to confirm the domain ownership)